# Java Applet : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, applet

I am making a Java Applet to sign PDF from client side and I encounter the following error when launching the applet in Internet Explorer :

[image: The error I get]

This is my folder architecture :

```
Test/
├── Applet.html/
├── PDFSigningApplet.class/
├── jars/
│   └── bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar
│   └── bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar
│   └── itextpdf-5.5.11.jar
│   └── itext-pdfa-5.5.11.jar
│   └── ...
```

Here is my **HTML** code :

```
<html> 

<head> 
<title>Test Smart Card Signer Applet</title> 
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

</head> 

<body>
    <script>
        var attributes = {
                          codebase: '.',
                          code: 'PDFSigningApplet.class',
                          archive: 'jars/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar, ' +
                                  'jars/bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar, ' +
                                  'jars/signing-pdf-applet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, ' +
                                  'jars/commons-imaging-1.0-20170517.221134-118.jar, ' +
                                  'jars/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, ' +
                                  'jars/itextpdf-5.5.11.jar, ' +
                                  'jars/itext-pdfa-5.5.11.jar, ' +
                                  'jars/itext-xtra-5.5.11.jar, ' +
                                  'jars/xmlworker-5.5.11.jar',
                          width: '800',
                          height: '600'
                         };
        var parameters = {java_arguments: ''}; // customize per your needs Xmx256m
        var version = '1.8'; // JDK version
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
        console.log("Ran script");
    </script>
    ...
```

And here is the use of BouncyCastleProvider in my **Applet.java** :

```
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
...
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
```

The strange thing here is that all other external libraries seem to have been well imported but I get the exception with BouncyCastleProvider.

**What I have already tried based on the similar questions found online :**

- Signed all of my jars using the following commands :

  jar ufm myjar.jar addToManifest

  jarsigner my.jar myKey

With this in my addToManifest :

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: file:///C:/Users/A667080/Desktop/Test/
Application-Name: PDFSigningApplet
```

- Added a security exception for this site in my Java setup
- I verified using 7-zip that my BouncyCastle jar contains the .class used in my applet

Did I miss anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a few more hours I finally found the issue. I had done all of those setps correctly but :

- Java was caching all of my jar files so nothing could have changed meanwhile. To change this, go to Control Panel (or System Preferences) > Java > General > Settings and then uncheck the box that says "Keep temporary files on my computer"
- I had not rebuilt my jars, so none of my changes affected my applet. To rebuild using Maven use `mvn -U clean install` or `jar -cvf DigitalSignerApplet.jar *.class` otherwise.

I hope it will help some people in the future.